# MySQL Set a value in a field on before insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `before insert` trigger as below:

```sql
SET new.currbal=(SELECT balance FROM customer WHERE customer.cust_no=new.cust_no);
```

`currbal` does exist in the table but it is not part of the insert string. `Currbal` remains at null even though the statement would return a value.
Is this because `currbal` is not in the insert command?

Comment: Are you sure the subquery is returning a value? Please provide a [mre] with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can set a column's value in a trigger even if the column is not named in the INSERT statement that spawned the trigger.

The most likely explanation is that your subquery did not match any rows in the `customer` table. That is, there are no rows in `customer` that match `customer.cust_no=new.cust_no`.

Comment: This looks like a running balance column in a transactions table. I'd expect `cust_no` to be a foreign key to the `customer` table, so there has to be a matching row.

Comment: @Barmar, Sure, it would be if you or I designed it, but we don't know if there is a foreign key constraint. We don't know if new.cust_no is NULL, either.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I can do this, helps with investigation. Yes there is a matching record where customer.cust_no=new.cust_no and it does have a balance, Running that query outside the trigger does return a balance of 55.22.